# How to remove an item from JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript structure:

```
obj = [
   {
      "patient_category_id":1,
      "patient_category_alias":"He",
      "patient_category_name":"Hello",
      "translate_id":null,
      "active":1
   },
   {
      "patient_category_id":2,
      "patient_category_alias":"Hi",
      "patient_category_name":"Hilo",
      "translate_id":null,
      "active":1
   }];
```

I want to remove **translate_id** and **active**, then insert **created**, like this:

```
obj = [
   {
      "patient_category_id":1,
      "patient_category_alias":"He",
      "patient_category_name":"Hello",
      "created": 'xxxx'
   },
   {
      "patient_category_id":2,
      "patient_category_alias":"Hi",
      "patient_category_name":"Hilo",
      "created": 'xxxx'
   }];
```

Comment: [how to remove a property from a javascript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delete obj.translate_id;
delete obj.active;
obj.created = 'xxxx';
```

Comment: `for(var x in obj){
delete obj.translate_id;
delete obj.active;
obj.created = 'xxxx';
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
delete obj[0].translate_id;
delete obj[1].translate_id;

delete obj[0].active;
delete obj[1].active;

obj[0].created = "xxxx";
obj[1].created = "xxxx";
```

or you could use

```
delete obj[0]["translate_id"]; // deletes translate_id from the first one
delete obj[1]["translate_id"]; // deletes translate_id from the second one

delete obj[0]["active"];
delete obj[1]["active"];

obj[0]["created"] = "xxxx"; // creates created in the first one
obj[1]["created"] = "xxxx"; // creates created in the second one
```